# 301 redirect all root-level pages with a list of exceptions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am in the process of migrating a website from Wordpress to a new platform (Craft CMS) and I need to set up some 301 redirects via .htaccess.

Blog posts in the old website resided in the root, I need to redirect them all to a /blog/ folder (slug is the same). Of course, because they are in the root domain there's a bunch of pages there that won't be redirected—I need to exclude these (and their sub-pages) from the redirect.

How would I do this? I tried to cobble something together using information I could glean from searching but I just end up with a redirect loop:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(blog|about-bluegg-creative|what-we-do|what-we-do|doodles|contact|legal-stuff|admin) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It's probably worth mentioning that there are other redirects going on in my .htaccess so the solution needs to play nicely with those. Here's a gist of the relevant parts: https://gist.github.com/hamishtaplin/c8d5e39d4621f56038d8

Answer (score 2):

You don't want that `[OR]` flag. What that is doing is logically *or* of two negative matches, which means either of those will go through since you only need to negate *one or the other*.

You just want:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(blog|about-bluegg-creative|what-we-do|what-we-do|doodles|contact|legal-stuff|admin) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've got other stuff going on in my .htaccess (added link in original post). Just adding your amended code results in a further redirect loop.

Comment: @hamishtaplin did you add this rule to the top? It needs to be first (or just under the www redirect)

Comment: No, I will try that tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Same problem. It's just going in to a loop.